# how to change branch with uncommited test file in working director

Tags: git, version-control

I have some test files in one of my branches and these files are not anything close to solid. what should I do when I want to temporarily switch to another branch?

should I commit the dummy files and as the project goes on I fix them and commit the changes? 
if I do this there will be a record of all these files in the commit beside the fact that half of these files are test file and should be deleted in the final project

if I stash them there will be another problem. I should put the changes into stash every time I want to switch and after that get it out of git stash every time

and even if I create a dev branch, like 'admin-dev' and work on it until it gets to a stable place, when I merge them to the main branch e.g. 'admin' all the early commits of those dummy files would exist in the 'admin'.

i don't know what is the best solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always ask to stash. If the files are *new* (in the sense of untracked), make sure to add before stashing:

```
git stash push "these tests are not ready yet"
```

That creates a new stash object and your working tree gets cleaned up. Then you can go anywhere,... when you want to come back you checkout the branch where you stashed and run:

```
git stash pop
```

Stash also is a nice resource if you want to move uncommitted changes from one branch to another.t

Answer (score 1):

In this case the best possible solution would be if you create a branch from a stash.

```
git stash branch testchanges
```

It creates a new branch for you, checks out the commit you were on when you stashed your work, reapplies your work there, and then drops the stash if it applies successfully.

I hope it would apply for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

`git stash` to store it and then `git stash pop`.

Comment: The OP has already mentioned that using `git stash` and `git stash pop` would not solve his problem in the second point.